# Understanding IIR , Low Pass, High Pass, Chebyshev, Elliptic Filter?

Tags: fft, dft, lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response

I see these terms everyday in every lecture, I do read stuff from wikipedia, follow lecture notes, study solved exercises. All in all I do have a rough idea about these, I know a little from everything, but the picture is not complete, far from complete, I would like to understand all of them and improve myself because in 2 weeks I will have an exam, is there a website which you can suggest, describing these very well? Animations would be great, I'm clueless from where shall I start and how do I close all these gaps :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not posed any particular problems and asking for animations? I think that books are way better. We don't know what are your topics, but knowing you did all the studying and have two weeks so I suggest to:

- Do the [ELEC301x – Discrete Time Signals and Systems](http://web.ece.rice.edu/richb/2013/08/18/elec301x-discrete-time-signals-and-systems-coming-in-january-2014-to-edx/) course from the Rice University. They do have a good part about design of digital filters, especially about differences between different topologies (including placement of zeros and poles), just [**watch**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX2owQF3Cq8).
- Design few filters in MATLAB, do some filtering and try to understand their characteristics. `fvtool` is great, especially if you want to visualize anything you need.
- Do the exams from past and if you feel confident then just go for a pint!
- Read all the questions and answers on DSP SE regarding digital filters ;)

Yep, and after typing into google "digital filter applet" for example you can get: 
[link1](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/java/Filter.html), [link2](http://iowahills.com/4IIRFilterPage.html), [link3](http://t-filter.appspot.com/fir/index.html).